# Сортирова Vue js Vuex

Tags: vue.js, сортировка, vuex

Как при клике сортировать массив, который хранится во vuex (например по дате)?
Пробую так. Создаю мутацию

```
sort(state, dt) {
    return state.ads.dt.sort((a, b) => b - a)
},
```

В компоненте вызываю так

```
methods: {
    sortedArray() {
        this.$store.commit('sort')
    },
}
```

В шаблоне

```
<v-btn
  class="success"
  @click="sortedArray"
>
   sort ad
</v-btn>
```

> Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

Comment: ну для сортировки масмива используй js функцию sort

Comment: ак я и использую

Comment: Что непонятного? У вас `state.ads.dt === undefined`, вот с этим и боритесь.

Comment: Плюс у вас мутация `sort` предполагает передачу обязательного аргумента `dt`, а в вашем примере ничего не передается: `this.$store.commit('sort')`. Вангую что вы хотели написать `return state.ads[dt].sort((a, b) => b - a)`